# Select the word that contains "ie" in Eclipse Find/Replace

Tags: regex, eclipse, find

I want to select the alphabets that have 'ie' together but not  'i?e' i.e. not any other alphabet between 'ie' So I tried this in Eclipse Find/Replace

Find: (\w?i\w?e?i?e)
which finds both of the words as following

1. file.
2. fiel.

I only want to make sure that any word that contains 'ie' together should be found rather than 'ile'. How can I approach?

Comment: Have you tried simply finding `ie`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
(ie|ei)
```

The `|` character is used for alternation, it basically acts like an OR, so this would mean "match `ie` or `ei` and capture in group 1".

Comment: Great. That was easy.